# Polymer 1.0: <iron-meta> usage

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0, custom-element

Proper usage of the Polymer 1.0 element `<iron-meta>` is confusing. Here is the [link on Github](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-meta). And here is the link to the [Polymer demo site](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta).

**Can someone please provide a proper code example of how to make it work?**

This is the code I have so far.

```
<dom-module id="generic-element">
  <style>...</style>
  <template>
    <iron-meta id="meta" key="info" value="foo/bar"></iron-meta>
    The <code>value</code> stored at <code>key="info"</code> is <code><span>{{test}}</span></code>. 
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'generic-element',
      properties: {
        test: {
          value: function(){
            return "Hello world"; // This is the only thing I can get to work so far.
         // return (new Polymer.IronMetaQuery({key: 'info'}).value); // Doesn't totally break.
         // All my other below attempts totally fail. Everything breaks.
         // return this.$.meta.IronMetaQuery({key: 'info'}).value;
         // return this.IronMetaQuery({key: 'info'}).value;
         // return this.$.meta.byKey('info').getAttribute('value');
         // return this.$.meta.byKey('info').value;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-meta/issues/11) to the issue. And here is a [Github repository](https://github.com/veronicawwashington/polymer-sandbox/blob/master/app/elements/my-auth-register/my-auth-register.html) that contains the complete problem code in context of the complete web app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are trying to set your element property's default value *to something that's declared inside that same element's template* itself. Two of the things that happen between the time when the element is **created** and when that element is **attached** include a) properties' default values are set; and b) the template undergoes preparations to be stamped into DOM. These tasks happen asynchronously so in essence you are generating a race condition.

Try setting your `test` default value inside the `ready()` callback - the `ready()` callback guarantees that DOM is ready to be accessed, which in your case is exactly where you declared your `<iron-meta>` key.

```
<dom-module id="generic-element">
  <style>...</style>
  <template>
    <iron-meta id="meta" key="info" value="foo/bar"></iron-meta>
    The <code>value</code> stored at <code>key="info"</code> is <code><span>{{test}}</span></code>. 
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'generic-element',
      properties: {
        test: String
      },
      ready: function () {
        // this will work
        this.test = this.$.meta.byKey("info");
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/vosekiwehu/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks. This worked but there is an error in your code.
    `this.$.test = this.$.meta.byKey("info");`
should be:
    `this.test = this.$.meta.byKey("info");`
But your general idea works. So I will accept your answer and upvote it. If you get a moment, you might want to revise your answer for those who follow who might benefit from it.

Comment: Oh yes, good catch. Sorry for the typo. I've corrected it. Thanks.